# Search multiple tabs at one time

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I'm am looking to create an ubersearch for reps at my company.  I need to be able to search multiple applications at one time, one per tab.

Examples of this are:

- Confluence
- Fogbugz
- Knowledge base.

I'm really just looking for a way to send search criteria to about five tabs and submit at one time.